# Is there any value in using macvlan/VLANs to create router aware networks to segment internet exposed containers vs non exposed containers?

Tags: network, docker, dmz

I have a single home server with a single NIC. I intend to run numerous Docker containers -- some will be internet exposed, some will not.

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Use the normal `bridge` network driver:

   1. Create 2 unique bridge networks to segment the traffic:

      1. One for internet exposed Docker containers
      2. One for non-internet exposed containers
   2. Use `-p` in my `docker run` to expose my hosts ports for containers
   3. Use port forwarding on my router to redirect WAN ports to the necessary ports on `host`
   4. For example:

      1. Docker networks: `network1` and `network2`
      2. Docker containers: `container1` on `network1` and `container2` on `network2`
      3. `host:1234` maps to `:2345` of `container1` on `network1`
      4. `host:5678` maps to `:6789` of `container2` on `network2`
      5. Port forwarding of my router to forward `WAN:443` to `host:1234`
2. Use `macvlan`:

   1. Create router aware VLAN networks in Docker with containers in their own VLAN network
   2. No need to use `-p` with `docker run` since the containers have router aware IPs and I can just access them using `[IP of container]:[service port]`
   3. Use port forwarding on my router to redirect WAN ports to to the `IP of the container`
   4. For example:

      1. Docker networks: `network3` on `eth0.30` and `network4` on `eth0.40`
      2. Docker containers: `container3` on `network3` and `container4` on `network4`
      3. port forward `WAN:443` to the `[IP of container3]:2345`

Both give the same end result. `macvlan` makes my containers router aware. One way the traffic is segmented by Docker, and one they are segmented by my router and the 802.1q trunk.

I appreciate any thoughts, perspective, advice. TIA!